# Is there better way to get multiple field as a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, attributes

I need to get a list: `[A.sample.name, A.species.name, A.factor.name, A.cell.name, A.population.name]`

However, this list is very long (about 20 elements) and all element comes from the same pattern `A.fieldname.name`. I think I can use `[A.__dict__[i].name for i in ["sample", "species", "factor", "cell", "population"]` to do this job, but I'm not sure whether that's the most recommended way.

Does anyone know whether there're other ways to do this job? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `getattr()`

```
[getattr(A, attr).name for attr in ["sample", "species", "factor", "cell", "population"]
```